# How to Print the Disabled text from Geb/Groovy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CBHQ.jpg)

We are automating the UI Application, Our UI application have Disabled Text are present, so we need to Validate the Disabled text. Before validating, I have to Print the Disabled text, Please guide me to how to print the text using Geb/Groovy.
Please find the Image of  HTML tag which i highlighted is the Disabled text

BNSF0000712570

BNSF0000712570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector above will yield multiple results, i.e. elements, if there is more than one element that matches the classes used in the By.cssSelector query.

To get only the element containing "BNSF0000712570", I would suggest you try to get it using the "ext:qtip" attribute instead (which I assume is unique per element containing a disabled text) on the div containing the disabled text:

```
def myText = $(“div[ext:qtip=‘Id: 0001’]”).text();
println myText;
assert myText == "BNSF0000712570";
```

@Saurabh Gar: Why would you use the WebDriver "By" class selectors? With Geb you have access to a wide range of simpler ways to write selectors, e.g. like the one used above.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `By.cssSelector` as below :-

```
def text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.x-grid3-td-elementvalue").text
```

Or

```
def text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-elementvalue").text

assert text == "BNSF0000712570"
println text
```

**Note**:- If still doesn't get the text need to share table HTML insteadof screenshot that's why, could make a best locator.

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks Saurab for your quick reply, i try to use the css selector, its not working. see below HTML for disable text

<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-elementvalue x-selectable noneditablecell" style="width: 236px;" tabindex="0">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-elementvalue" ext:qtitle="Equipment ID" ext:qtip="Id: 0001">BNSF0000712570 </div>
</td>

Comment: @GopalaKrishnan what do you mean not working?? Is there any exception??